# Is it possible that $L+L^T$ is a positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, positive-definite, graph-laplacian

If $L$ is a nonsymmetric Laplacian matrix, is it possible that $L+L^T$ is a positive definite matrix?

Comment: How is it possible to have a nonsymmetric Laplacian matrix?

Comment: If the graph is directed or if the weights of the edges are not the same then the corresponding Laplacian matrix is nonsymmetric.

Comment: And in that case, what is the degree of a vertex in a directed graph, so that we can compute $D-A$?

Comment: You can read some paper on formation control. In a nutshell, this kind of matrix looks like $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -10 & 10\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. It is impossible for $L+L^T$ to be a positive definite matrix. This is because of 
\begin{align}
    1^T(L+L^T)1 &= 1^TL1 + 1^T L^T 1 \\
                &= 1^T(L1) + (L1)^T 1 \\
                &= 0
\end{align}
which has used the property $L1=0$. Therefore, this contradicts the definition of a positive definite matrix. This means $L+L^T$ has at least one non-positive eigenvalue.